# dynamic value sql

Tags: sql, dropdown

My dropdown return value 2014 and 2015

```
<select><option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

and my query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, value
FROM sales
WHERE year IN ('2015') ";
```

How I can do my query dynamic, depend on dropdown?

Thank you!

Comment: Missing a lot of code that should be between the query and the dropdown, please update your question so that it is more clear.

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing the platform you are using -- clearly the drop down is not created in SQL.  What environment is your website running in... what flavor of SQL are you using -- these things matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the selected value, place it into a variable, then assemble the query string, concatenating the command and this variable.

I recommend some data binding framework to perform this kind of task for you.

What's your development environment? PHP?

Try this with PHP:

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELE‌​CT name, value FROM sales WHERE year = :year");

$stmt->bind_param(":‌​year", $year); $year = $_POST['year'];

$stmt->execute()

Comment: No, no concatenation (read about SQL injection). Better use parameters...

Comment: This answer is recommending an solution which is very bad because of sql injection attacks -1

Comment: Then it should be something like:

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, value FROM sales WHERE year = :year");
$stmt->bind_param(":year", $year);

$year = $_POST['year'];
$stmt->execute();

Comment: @ADNnetPonzo Hi, please place this last comment into your answer.  I did not down vote you, but with this answer I'd happily upvote